# Why this php code does not produce any errors?

Tags: php

Could anyone elaborate on that

```
$string = "faisal";
echo b"$string";
```

the `b` is making me wonder, why is the code still valid, i mean i am not getting any compiler errors.

Comment: Thank you Qirel for your assistance.